# Selenium (Python) - getting the value inside a button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I'm trying to get the value inside a button using selenium.

My code is:

```
getphone = profile.find_element_by_class_name('app-emp-phone-txt').click().find_element_by_tag_name("p")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag_name'
```

What should I write in my code ?

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `find_element` from method (`click`) call which returns `None`. Try to update your code:

```
getphone = profile.find_element_by_class_name('app-emp-phone-txt')
getphone.click()
getphone.find_element_by_tag_name("p")
```

**Update**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.mariages.net/domaine-mariage/la-tour-des-plantes--e129089')

getphone = driver.find_element_by_class_name('app-emp-phone-txt')
getphone.click()
number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".app-dropdown-show-phone>.storefrontDrop__tag").text
print(number)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is I'm getting this error now:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"p"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.146)

Comment: @DylanG probably you need to use [Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits). Its hard to tell without seeing page

Comment: This is the page: https://www.mariages.net/domaine-mariage/la-tour-des-plantes--e129089

Comment: @DylanG what exactly you want to get as output?